# RegexKitLite issue

Tags: iphone, ios, regexkitlite

I installed RegexKitLite and everything functioning well, except there are many "analyzer results" about potential leaks when compiling the app. These warning are from the RegexKitLite.m

Do I missing something during the installation?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before posting a question on Stack Overflow, you did make an effort to figure it out yourself, right?  I'm just asking because this basically involves pushing that mouse pointer you see on your screen over one of those analyzer warnings and clicking.  This will cause the offending line to be displayed in the editor.  And on that offending line, there are comments such as:

```
// .. but only if this is not replacing a mutable self.  Warning about potential leak can be safely ignored.
// otherwise, create a new string.  Warning about potential leak can be safely ignored.
// The two warnings about potential leaks can be safely ignored.
// Warning about potential leak of Core Foundation object can be safely ignored.
// Warning about potential leak can be safely ignored.
```

... which would seem to suggest that someone, possibly the author, has investigated these warnings and determined that they are "false positives".  There's probably even bugs filed with `clang` about a few of these.